# I only want this function to alert that the book was not found once after it iterated through the bookStore Array not at every indices.

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, for-loop

```
function checkStore(string) {
    for (var i = 0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
        if (BookStore[i].title === string) {
            prompt('We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + BookStore[i].author +
                '. It costs ' + BookStore[i].price +
                ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
        } else {
            alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happens lets say the BookStore.length = 6. If `BookStore[i].title === string` is true at index 4 this is what i get

```
'Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?'
'Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?'
'Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?'
'Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?'
'We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + BookStore[i].author +
                    '. It costs ' + BookStore[i].price +
                    ' would you like to add it to your cart?'
'Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?'
```

How do i get it to just print `'Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?'` once when not true and

```
'We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + BookStore[i].author +
                        '. It costs ' + BookStore[i].price +
                        ' would you like to add it to your cart?'
```

by itself when true?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `Array.prototype.some()`:

```
function checkStore(string) {
    var book;
    if (BookStore.some(function (b) {
        return b.title === string && (book = b);
    })) {
        prompt('We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + book.author + '. It costs ' + book.price + ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
    } else {
        alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make the job ;)

```
function checkStore(string) {
    var foundBook;
    for (var i = 0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
        if (BookStore[i].title === string) {
            foundBook = BookStore[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(foundBook)
        prompt('We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + foundBook.author +
                '. It costs ' + foundBook.price +
                ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
    else 
        alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The least amount of editing would lead to something like this:

```
function checkStore(string) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
        if (BookStore[i].title === string) {
            prompt('We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + BookStore[i].author +
                '. It costs ' + BookStore[i].price +
                ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
    }
}
```

However, it's probably better to refactor it:

```
function findBookByTitle(title) {
    for (var i=0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
        if (BookStore[i].title == title) 
            return BookStore[i];
    }
    return null; // not found
}

function checkStore(title) {
    var book = findBookByTitle(title);
    if (!book) {
        alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
        return;
     }
     prompt('We found your book! ' + book.title + ', by ' + book.author +
            '. It costs ' + book.price +
            ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
}
```

And note that in ES6 you could use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function checkStore(title) {
    var book = BookStore.find(function (book) { return book.title === title; });
    if (!book) {
        alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
        return;
     }
     prompt('We found your book! ' + book.title + ', by ' + book.author +
            '. It costs ' + book.price +
            ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function checkStore(string) {
         var notFound = false;
         for (var i = 0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
           if (BookStore[i].title === string) {
              notFound = false;
              prompt('We found your book! ' + string + ', by ' + BookStore[i].author +
                '. It costs ' + BookStore[i].price +
                ' would you like to add it to your cart?');
        } else {
            notFound = true;
        }
    }
if (notFound){
   alert('Sorry ' + string + ' was not found, try another title?');
}
}
```

Assumption: Each book's name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the previous answers will do the trick. The reason why you were getting the output before was you were:

- Checking the iterated item against the item you passed into the function

  - If it was the item you were looking for you printed "Book found"
  - If it was not the item you were look for you printed "Book not found"

The problem was you iterated through the whole list and did not stop when you found the book. Plus you printed a line for each iteration through the list.

So the new logic is:

- Go through all the items and compare to the book you are looking for

  - Set a flag if you find it
- Check your flag

  - If your flag is set then print out the "Book found" string
  - If your flag is not set print out the "Book not found" string

I hope this helps you understand what was going wrong other than just telling you how to fix it.